# makefile subst doesn't use make variable as expected

Tags: makefile, subst

in a makefile I use subst to assign a value to a make variable, and it uses another make variable in the subst parameters, but it's not really working as expected :

```
USER_HOME := $(shell echo ~$$SUDO_USER)
EXP_VAR := $(subst $$HOME_PATH,$(USER_HOME),"$$HOME_PATH/project/dir")

all:
    @echo $(USER_HOME)
    @echo $(EXP_VAR)
```

and the output of make is :

```
/home/me
~/project/dir
```

instead of the expected :

```
/home/me
/home/me/project/dir
```

so it seems that the variable `$(USER_HOME)` is correctly assigned the value `/home/me`, but incorrectly assigned `~` when used in the subst function

I don't see anything explaining a special treatment of make variables here on the presentation of the subst function : https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html

I can imagine that the subst function does not use the value of the `$(USER_HOME)`, and instead runs the `$(shell echo ~$$SUDO_USER)` command again, but certainly there is something that prevents the expansion of the shell command, so it only output the literal string `~$$SUDO_USER` and fails to expend `$SUDO_USER` so it ends up being `~`

I can solve the problem with a little more complicated command that i found here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247582, but I don't understand why i should need it in the first place :

```
USER_HOME := $(shell eval echo "~$$SUDO_USER")
```

in this case, if i understand correctly :

- makefile expand `$$` : `USER_HOME := $(shell eval echo "~$SUDO_USER")`
- then echo output a string : `~$SUDO_USER`
- then eval expand the string : `/home/me`
- and this output is assigned to the variable `$(USER_HOME)` and in the subst function

But why the subst function doesn't use the value of the make variable `$(USER_HOME)` instead of, apparently, expanding the `$(shell echo ~$$SUDO_USER)` command again ?

And also, but not as important, why the expansion works differently in the subst function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing many problematic things which are leading to your confusion.

First, you should never use `@` to hide make's output of your recipe when you are trying to debug makefiles.  That's like sending the output of your compiler to `/dev/null`.  This is always Rule #1 for Debugging Makefiles.

Second, you should always quote make variables when you show them via `echo`.  Otherwise the shell will get at them and manipulate them for you so you can't see what the contents really are.  E.g., you should use `echo '$(USER_HOME)'` not `echo $(USER_HOME)`.

Third, you should just use built-in make functions like `$(info ...)` to show the values of variables, not shell commands like `echo` because between the invocation of the shell and the output generated, you can't tell what the real value was.  E.g., you should say `$(info USER_HOME is $(USER_HOME))` or similar.

If you do all the above things, your understanding of what is happening will be very different (note, I'm ignoring the syntax error of the extra close-paren on the second line of the example: I'm assuming that's some kind of cut and paste artifact).

In fact, this line:

```
USER_HOME := $(shell echo ~$$USER)
```

(assuming the environment variable `$USER` is set to `me`) sets the value of `USER_HOME` to `~me`, not `/home/me`.  And this line:

```
EXP_VAR := $(subst $$HOME_PATH,$(USER_HOME),"$$HOME_PATH/project/dir")
```

sets the value of `EXP_VAR` to `"~me/project/dir"` (note the double quotes here!!  make doesn't know or care about quotes in virtually any situation; they're just another character like `a` or `b` as far as make is concerned).

Now if you look at what make runs in the recipe (be removing the `@` before the `echo` commands), you'll see that it runs:

```
echo ~me
echo "~me/project/dir"
```

The output of the first line is `/home/me`, and the output of the second line is `~me/project/dir` because the string is quoted the shell doesn't do tilde-expansion on the text.

Comment: perfect, thx for the numerous advices and explanation
I removed the parenthesis error
I didn't realized Make would use sh, it actually make sense. In zsh that i use, the expansion of `"~$USER"` would be ~me, but the expansion of `~$USER` without double quotes will be `/home/me`, I didn't realized all this differences, I need to explore them nore